# Cycle through a list of buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to have something like this:

- A list of buffer is display
- As I select a buffer in the list, it's content is display immediately.
- The list can be in minibuffer (preferred) or in a separate window

Is there a plug in for this?

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42051/how-to-set-up-emacs-to-cycle-through-files/42058#42058 That solution works if the buffers are associated with files and can be selected via filtering the file names by a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found what I wanted (although a bit differed from what I wanted, but it got the essential feature right): https://github.com/martinp26/cycbuf

It automatically display buffers with a list of buffer as the cursor move at a buffer name. Customize variable `cycbuf-clear-delay` to adjust the time the buffer list is toggled; after exceeding the delay, the buffer list is automatically turned off and the buffer is picked.

Answer (score 0):

`^x^b` displays a list of buffers, then you can click on one. Is that what you want?

Comment: No. I mean the list of buffer remains, and as I move the cursor, its content is display automatically in another window. If I press `C-g`, I return to the original buffer and `RET` for entering the buffer at point.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives. For discussion on these, see for example http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ControlTABbufferCycling

Answer (score 0):

There's many options. Some are:

- to display a list of buffers: ibuffer is an option http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode
- to have the list in the minibuffer: ido-switch-buffer http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Ido#Virtual_Buffers or you can use helm's interface http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Helm

Answer (score 0):

The EmacsWiki pages cited in the other answers (so far) are a subset of the wiki's main page for this topic, which is [where you should start](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers#toc4).

(That wiki page is also a good place for other answers, which do not cite EmacsWiki, to update. ;-) )